# How long does it take for a UK Visa application in New Delhi?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I applied for my UK tourist visa on 30th March and got an SMS saying my application has been sent to the embassy. I haven't heard anything since. Any idea how long they typically take for processing or the next update? Because there is no way to track it online.

Comment: @Vince's excellent answers covers it all. In addition to the average 10 *business* days processing time, from personal experience there are times when the Embassy does a deeper investigation into your application and calls you for an interview. This could either be because of something suspicious in your application or (in my case, as I was told) random sample checks they do.

Answer (score 9):

The Home Office provides [a tool (in beta version) to estimate the time your application will take](https://visa-processingtimes.homeoffice.gov.uk/). The announced duration is in business days.

For General Visit visas from New Delhi, 98% of applications take 10 business days or less. You should go through the estimation process with your specific situation (since I don't know your precise situation). But a priori that's not too bad you got no answer yet.

It has been only 4 business days so far, usually 5 applications in 6 are processed within this timeframe. Last Friday and today (Monday) were [bank holidays](https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays) in the UK so the embassy employees were not working. I didn't find if there is any Indian holiday, if so it would make the process even longer. Your application may take another 10 calendar days without it being abnormally long.